# Humming sound from car when driving

Tags: wheels, car, noise, bearing

I have a Nissan FB 15 car. Today I can hear some humming sound from the front of the car. I'm not sure whether it comes from the engine or wheels. 
It's happening all the time. But when I increase the speed, the humming sound occurs more.
But when I break, humming sound stops. Is it coming from hub razor? 
To solve this problem what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine whether it's coming from the hub (and on which side), shift into neutral and lift the front of the car. (Set the parking brake and block the wheels very well!) Spin the wheel rapidly with your hand. You should be able to hear the same noise.

To repair, usually you replace the hub. It is possible to repair a hub by repacking the bearings, but it might be a bit much for DIY.

Comment: It's not coming for lower speeds. It's coming after 40 kmh-1

Comment: @chackrapani That was also true in my case, but you can still hear the sound when spinning it by hand.

Comment: I recently had a wheel bearing go bad on my Pontiac and I was quite surprised by how easy it was to replace. Literally, take off the wheel, take off the brake caliper, remove the CV nut (had to get an extra-big wrench), three bolts to remove the hub, and then put it all back together. I had the whole thing done in less than an hour.